# Why I can access btn.Caption when btn is NIL?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe7

Why this code does not crash? `T` is nil. How it is possible to access `Caption` if `T` is `nil`?

```
procedure Crash;                                                                          
VAR T: TButton;
begin
 T:= NIL;
 T.Caption:= ''; <---------- this works
end;
```

Comment: @KenWhite That's what I thought too, but I just tested, and no matter what value I pass, it still doesn't crash. Internally, it successfully sends Windows messages for `WM_SETTEXT` and `CM_TEXTCHANGED`.

Comment: Because it is wrapper around Windows control that uses messages to set actual values. And it has safe guard that prevents sending messages on nil controls. Of course, it also works because property setter is not virtual.

Comment: @Ken Setting caption to the empty string certainly does do something.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The `TButton` control is a wrapper around the Win32 Button control. It uses the Windows messaging system to operate upon it. And the core method for doing so, `TControl.Perform()`, has a built in safeguard against sending messages if `Self` is `nil`:

```
function TControl.Perform(Msg: Cardinal; WParam: WPARAM; LParam: LPARAM): LRESULT;
var
  Message: TMessage;
begin
  Message.Msg := Msg;
  Message.WParam := WParam;
  Message.LParam := LParam;
  Message.Result := 0;

  if Self <> nil then // <-- here
    WindowProc(Message); 

  Result := Message.Result;
end;
```

`Caption` is a property whose setter uses the non-virtual `TControl.GetText()` and `TControl.SetText()` methods, which can be safely called upon `nil` objects, as their functionality rely on sending various messages (`WM_GETTEXTLEN` and `WM_SETTEXT`) to the control, and only involve local variables or passed parameters.  So the actual object is not accessed when `nil`, thus no crash.