# There is guarantee that accessing a nil pointer will raise an exception?

Tags: delphi

Remy Lebeau [stated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55891739/when-to-raise-an-exception?noredirect=1#comment98451974_55891739) that "There is no guarantee that accessing a nil pointer will raise an exception. It is undefined behavior. Anything could happen. An exception might be raised, or you might just read garbage, or you might trash memory, or ...". How come? 
In which circumstances, accessing the methods of a NIL object will NOT raise an AV AND lead to memory corruption?

```
// (Obj is any kind of object. Let's say TStringList) 
Obj = nil;
Obj.LoadFromFile();
```

Comment: Depends on what you mean by "access".

Comment: @UliGerhardt - I added an example.

Comment: Related: [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51161223)

Comment: @BrakNicku - the answer of that question clearly specify why SOME properties are SPECIAL. In this case, obviously what Remy said does not apply. AND you have no crash (AV). However, Remy stated that (in the other cases) this can lead to undefined behavior. Which I read it something like: "it let's you access the method (which results in undefined behavior)"

Comment: I think this question is off topic, since it seems to be 'why did Remy say this'. You already got the answer to the actual question about using nil reference (here and in two other incarnations of your question), and if you want to ask clarification about a specific comment, please do so in another comment. Also, I know it's hard to believe, but even Remy could maybe have made a mistake, or have chosen some poor wording in his comment, so maybe it's unfair to discard the various answers your got in favor of this one comment.

Comment: Remy is right. But in your question, it really depends on what you mean with **accessing**. If you mean **dereferencing**, then yes, it will cause an AV, or GPF or NilPointerException or whatever is appropriate on the platform. If you mean calling a method on a nil object, then it is not so clear. Then it depends on what that method does, if it is virtual/dynamic or not, etc. And since it is not clearly defined, it is called undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 8):

> There is no guarantee that accessing nil pointer will raise an
>   exception.

**True.**

However, the actual behavior depends on the actual code.

Exception will be raised if you call dynamic or virtual methods and when you try accessing the instance fields directly.

It is perfectly safe to call static method on `nil` reference and testing `Self` for `nil` inside it.

The best example of such static method is `Free`.

```
procedure TObject.Free;
begin
  if Self <> nil then
    Destroy;
end;
```

Obviously, above behavior is well defined, otherwise every Delphi program ever written would crash randomly (or all the time).

---

In general, accessing fields of `nil` reference will result in crash. In theory with large enough class anything is possible.

Example class provided by David Heffernan

```
type
   TSillyExample = class
     FStuff: array [0..SomeVeryLargeNumber-1] of Byte;
     FAreYouFeelingLucky: string;
   end;
```

Comment: I agree with you about Free and I also agree with BrakNicku about Caption. However, I think that Remy was speaking about something else: "An exception might be raised, or you might just read garbage, or you might trash memory, or ... ". In case of Free, none of the above will happen.

Comment: What he said can happen when you access dangling pointer, when you access nil behavior is pretty much defined, but what the actual result will be depends on the code.

Comment: I agree about dangling pointers. BUT he didn't mentioned a dangling pointer. He clearly said "there is no guarantee that accessing a NIL pointer will raise an exception". And then: "or you might just read garbage, or you might trash memory"

Comment: Obviously, I cannot speak for Remy and what he actually meant at the time... looking at your other question his comment makes sense even if not 100% correct. You asked whether you should return nil or raise an exception... comment was related to the assumption that if you return nil, any attempted usage of that reference will result in exception anyway, which is not true.

Comment: Strictly speaking this is incorrect. The fields can perfectly well be located in valid memory. The fields start at an address close to 0. If the object is large enough, then the address of some fields may be accessible.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan theoretically,yes. But, I have to admit, I haven't seen such example, yet.

Comment: In any case, accessing nil reference by mistake and hoping for AV is not good programming practice. On LLVM based compilers, even if exception is raised, it can escape immediate exception handler.

Comment: `type class = TSillyExample FStuff: array [0..SomeVeryLargeNumber-1] of Byte; FAreYouFeelingLucky: string; end;` But yes, in Windows at least, you have to work hard to get past the reserved area at the bottom of the virtual address space that extends to 0x0000ffff.